# Blender video edit rendered in Unreal Engine 5 Mac mini M2

Tags: osx, unreal-engine

Mac mini M2 24 GB RAM, Sonoma 14.1, Blender 3.3.1, unreal engine 5.3

Video clips are from iPhone 12 mini.

I get the clips into Blender, make the cuts, transitions etc. Save and set to "Render Animation".

I have hear unreal engine will render this in a minute or two what usually takes 1-3 hours when Blender Renders.

How do I get this Blender edit into unreal engine.

When unreal engine is launched all I see is something that looks like a chessboard.

Does anyone have the Next Step(s)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this a question about Blender or Unreal?

Comment: I have no idea how to edit videos in Unreal Engine and this site is about the use of Blender... I would edit videos in DaVinci Resolve though.